# BindableProperty in ViewCell

Tags: xaml, xamarin.forms, xamarin.forms.listview

I've transferred my `ViewCell` from the list-xaml to a separate one and now I struggle with binding the properties.

My `ListView`'s item source is an `ObservableCollection` of "member".

```
public class Member 
{
   public string Name { get; set; }
   public string Image { get; set; }
   public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

So now I'm trying to figure out how to use the bindable property within my MemberViewCell.

The examples I read are pretty straight forward, I create a BindableProperty for Name as well as a normal property for Name, when Name is modified it will trigger the graphical update.

Can I create a BindableProperty with the basis of Member so that I don't need to write all those bindables/property changed for each property I want exposed?

Something like this:

```
public static readonly BindableProperty MemberSource = BindableProperty.Create("Member", typeof(Member), typeof(ListViewMemberCell), null, defaultBindingMode: BindingMode.OneWay, propertyChanged: MemberSourcePropertyChanged);

public Member Member
{
    get { return GetValue(MemberSource) as Member; }
    set
    {
        SetValue(MemberSource, value);
    }
}

private static void MemberSourcePropertyChanged(BindableObject bindable, object oldValue, object newValue)
{
    ListViewMemberCell cell = (ListViewMemberCell)bindable;

    /// Set the different properties to my labels/images based on member.
}
```

Naturally I tried this first but as expected I get a compile error (within the consumer of this component).

```
<ListView.ItemTemplate>
     <DataTemplate>
          <memberCell:ListViewMemberCell Member="{Bindable}"/>
     </DataTemplate>
</ListView.ItemTemplate>
```

So, `{Bindable}` feels wrong and the error says so as well, but what I did when I had the ViewCell within the DataTemplate was to bind like this `{Bindable Name} /// Member.Name`...

I hope its just me misunderstanding the examples..

Comment: What do you want ? Why do you need Member to extend `ViewCell` ? I'm pretty sure you're mixing things over here

Comment: I don't want Member to extend ViewCell, but I want to pass my member object to my ViewCell to render the content (as described in the XAML). The reason I want my own ViewCell file for this, is because I will need to re-use it a lot.

Comment: Ok, I get it now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you'll need to name it `MemberSourceProperty`. The `Property` suffix is a requirement for every prop you create.

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding ListOfMembers}">
  <ListView.ItemTemplate>
   <DataTemplate>
      <!-- This will bind to the object being iterated (Member) -->
      <memberCell:ListViewMemberCell MemberSourceProperty="{Bindable .}"/> 
   </DataTemplate>
  </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

And of course you will need to load `memberCell` in the xaml headers. `ListOfMembers` should be an `ObservableCollection<Member>` that you have in the `BindingContext` of the View.

I'm assuming you will know what to do in the `ListViewMemberCell` class. To get the name or image, simply do: `Member.Name Member.Image ..`

Hope it helps

Comment: That's exactly what I've been looking for! So the key is the dot and also the Property requirement. Thanks a bunch I will give feedback once I've tested it.

Comment: I got a lot further with this now, I get all my members rendered with the static content, but the bindable content isn't rendered (though that was not part of this question).

Comment: Just kidding, I did a typo.. thanks a bunch @greggz.

Comment: @Alex Np, go nuts with XF ;)